# Timeout when running mocha test on mongoose model and express route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js, supertest

I'm having an issue writing tests for my Mongoose models **and** my express app (routes)

I have a very simple `app.js` file:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    express = require('express'),
    config = require('./config/config')[env],
    http = require('http'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Bootstrap db connection
mongoose.connect(config.db)

// Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/model';
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function(file) {
    if (~file.indexOf('.js')) {
        require(models_path + '/' + file);
    }
});

var app = express();

// express settings
require('./config/express')(app, config);

// Bootstrap routes
require('./config/routes')(app, compact);

if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('Server started on port ' + app.get('port'));
    })
}

module.exports = app;
```

I have a folder called `model` that contains my mongoose models.

I have a `test` folder, with `accountTest.js` - looks a bit like this:
(This is to test my Account model)

```
var utils = require('./utils'),
  should = require('chai').should(),
  Account = require('../app/model/account');

describe('Account', function() {
  var currentUser = null;
  var account = null;

  it('has created date set on save', function(done) {
    var account = new Account();

    account.save(function(err) {
      account.created.should.not.be.null;
      done();
    });
  });
```

utils is taken from here: http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/1/06

This works, if I leave it at just this one test.

If I add another test, to test my express route, something like this:

```
var request = require('supertest'),
    app = require('../../app'),
    should = require('chai').should();

describe('Account controller', function() {

    it('GET /account returns view', function(done) {
        //omitted for brevity
        done();
    });
});
```

Then I get a timeout error, on my tests for my model...

The line that is effecting it is `app = require('../../app')`
If I remove that, then there's no timeout.

I realise it may be something to do with the mongoose connection, but not sure how to "share" it between tests?

Answer (score 0):

mocha has a [root Suite](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/):

`You may also pick any file and add "root" level hooks, for example add beforeEach() outside of describe()s then the callback will run before any test-case regardless of the file its in. This is because Mocha has a root Suite with no name.`

Use that to start your Express server once (and we use an environment variable so that it runs on a different port than our development server):

```
before(function () {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  require('../../app.js');
});
```

(We don't need a `done()` here because require is synchronous.) This was, the server is started exactly once, no matter how many different test files include this root-level `before` function.

Comment: But I don't want / need to require app.js in my Mongoose model tests, or do I?

Comment: The basic idea is to use a before statement wrapped around all the tests that will need that functionality, to avoid calling it twice. You may just be able to require your Mongoose models, though if you have other tests that test Express and Express requires your models, then you may be better off just requiring Express.

Comment: Wyy would i require app.js (express) if I only want to test my model though... that doesn't make sense? Surely has to be a better way

Comment: Try just requiring your models.